# Ruby + Selenium - Take a screenshot with each step executed

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir

I want to take a screenshot with each step executed, the code below is taking a screenshot during the entire execution.

How to fix this?

**HOOKS.RB**

```
AfterStep do
  browser.screenshot.save 'screenshot.png'
  encoded_img = @browser.driver.screenshot_as(:base64)
    embed("data:image/png;base64,#{encoded_img}",'image/png')
end
```

**ENV.RB**

```
#encoding: utf-8
require 'rspec/expectations'
require 'watir'
require 'rspec'
require 'json'
require 'magic_encoding'
```

**RESULT EXPECTED**

[image: Result expected]

Comment: Are you sure a screenshot isn't being taken after each step? The problem might be that each screenshot is being saved with the same name - ie `browser.screenshot.save 'screenshot.png'` keeps overwriting the image of the previous step?

Comment: I commented this line and ran the test again, in the report html appears only the image of the first screen, in the 3 links of acreenshot.

Comment: Interesting. Your code works for me - ie I can get a different screenshot after each step. It might help if you can create a complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @JustinKo 
Inspect the hml element of the report I discovered that it gives a get in the id "img_0" and in the src of the img tag I saw that it really takes a print to each step, however at the time of writing in the html, the 3 screenshot links introduce me to same image, in this case the initial image.
Very strange this behavior.

Comment: What version of Cucumber are you using? I was using v3.1.0. The images/links generated were probably incremented. Interestingly, mine start at img_1 rather than img_0.

Comment: ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]

Comment: He is asking your Cucumber version not Ruby version.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the environment that I was using was with outdated gems, I solved this with the `gem update` command.

After refreshing the gems, screenshots are now taken correctly.